How to plot points on a graph curve under logarithmic coordinate axis
I am trying to draw a curve and set a special point based on the logarithmic abscissa, as shown in the following example. The function is 1/(1+(RCw)^2)^0.5.
f[w_, RC_] := 1/(1 + (RC*w)^2)^(1/2);
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[w, RC], {w, 0.001  RC, 1000 RC}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"w/RC", "|H(jw)|"}, 
  PlotLabel -> "RC Circuit Frequency Curve", 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{1/RC, f[1/RC, RC]}], 
    Dashed, Line[{{1/RC, 0}, {1/RC, f[1/RC, RC]}}]}], {RC, 1, 10}]

The graph is as follows

You can see that the point (RC, 1/√ 2) is far away from its actual position(even I set point (1, 1/√ 2) like Point[{1, 1/(2^0.5)}]). How can I display the correct point? Any reply is much appreciated

The ScalingFunctions option does not affect the Epilog option. You must explicitly take the Log in the Epilog

Similar 268080

Try
f[w_, RC_] := 1/(1 + (RC*w)^2)^(1/2);
Manipulate[
  LogLinearPlot[f[w, RC], {w, 0.001  RC, 1000 RC}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"w/RC", "|H(jw)|"}, 
    PlotLabel -> "RC Circuit Frequency Curve", 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{Log[1/RC], f[1/RC, RC]}], 
      Dashed, Line[{{Log[1/RC], 0}, {Log[1/RC], f[1/RC, RC]}}]}], {RC, 1, 10}]


thank you so much. Really appreciate
